# postgresql compilation ERROR

Tags: java, postgresql

Hello I have created a database called 'gestion', and a table called 'informationEmploye' in postgresql.

But when I try to insert information into 'informationEmploye' I get this error:

> ERROR: the relation « informationemploye » does not exist.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class databaseConnector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/gestion";
            String user = "postgres";
            String passwd = "asmaa";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            System.out.println("connected");
            Statement state = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into informationEmploye values (1,'name','noun')";
            state.execute(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you use capital letters, you need to use "informationEmploye"

Comment: This is not a compilation error, but a runtime error. Does the postgres user have access to your table? Can you show us the schema?

Comment: `informationemploye`  is a different table name than `"informationEmploye"`. See the manual for a complete explanation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS